# How to click on next button to scrape data from all pages using selenium python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

I've just started learning data scraping. I am using Selenium for that and storing the data in excel sheet. The issue is I am not able to figure out that how do I make selenium to loop click on next pages and scrape their data too until the pages run out.
To understand it better below is my complete code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/Neha/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)

driver.get('https://www.fundoodata.com/citiesindustry/19/2/list-of-information-technology-(it)-companies-in-noida')

company_names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('heading')

names_list = []

for name in company_names:
    text = name.text
    names_list.append(text)
    print(text)


driver.quit()


df = pd.DataFrame(names_list)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('companies_names.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='List')
writer.save()
```

**I want it to scrape company names from every pages.** The attribute and xPath of next button is -

```
<li><a href="/citiesindustry/19/2/list-of-information-technology-(it)-companies-in-noida?&amp;pageno=2&amp;tot_rows=606&amp;total_results=606&amp;no_of_offices=0">Next</a></li>
```

Xpath

```
//*[@id="main-container"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/div/ul/li[7]/a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a while loop, it would look something like this:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[rel=next]')
while len(links) > 0:
  driver.get(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
  # do stuff
  links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[rel=next]')
```

Comment: it's not working. You're suggesting css_selector but the a tag doesn't contain any css class just href and text saying 'next'.  If possible please visit to the site here for better understanding https://www.fundoodata.com/citiesindustry/19/2/list-of-information-technology-(it)-companies-in-noida

Comment: See my edit, it's there but it's a meta tag so you can't click it.